# Reversing strings using arrays and pointers both

Tags: c, string, pointers

i want to reverse a string using pointers. I get a Segmentation fault! Any ideas about that? 
Details are in the code. By the way, is this the right way to implement this stuff?

Thank you,

Gerhard!

MY CODE:

```
void copy_and_reverse(char* output, char* input) {

int c = 0;
int len = 0;
char *begin;
char *last;

len = strlen(input);
len -= 1;

begin = input;
last = output;

for (c = 0; c < len; c += 1) {
    last += 1;
}

len += 1;

 for (c = 0; c < len; c +=1, begin += 1, last -= 1 {
 temp = *begin;
 *last = *begin;  // Here is my problem. Why am I not allowed to access this storage? I have no Idea about that!
 }
 }

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

int i = 0;
int leng = 0;
char *input[999] = {0};  // input gets the string of the argument, the string should stay in the right order
char *output[999] = {0}; // output should get the reversed string



if (argc == 1) {
    printf("Too few arguments.");
    return -1;
}

for (i = 0; i < argc; i += 1, argv += 1) {
    if (strlen(*argv) > 100) {
        printf("Maximum string length exceeded.");
        return -2;
    }
}
argv -= i;  //Unnecessary stuff
*argv += 1;
argv += 1;
argc -= 1;


for (i = 0; i < argc; i += 1, argv += 1) {
    *input = *argv;
    copy_and_reverse(*output, *input);
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring:

```
void copy_and_reverse(char* output, char* input);
```

but you are calling:

```
copy_and_reverse(*output, *input);
```

where

```
char *input[999] = {0}; 
char *output[999] = {0};
```

In other words, you have defined an array of 999 pointers to char items, not a string of 999 char items as you probably intended.

And the trouble is you initialize the first element of output[] as 0, so *output == 0, in other words you pass a NULL pointer to copy_and_reverse(). When you try to reference that you get the segmentation fault.

What you would really need is:

```
char input[999] = {0}; 
char output[999] = {0};
```

and

```
copy_and_reverse(output, input);
```

and you should be ok.

There are other problems with the pasted code like @Mike S. mentions, but I believe these copy-paste oversights.

Comment: If do it like thischar input[999] = {0}; 
char output[999] = {0}; .. How could i give the argument(string) to the array? There's no chance to do this : *input = *argv; , any more, isn't it ?

Comment: Oh, yes you can, when defining char input[999]; the *input* is actually a (char*), so you can treat is like a pointer. When using the [] operator, say input[3] it is the equivallent of doing *(input + 3). Also, do take into account the points @Mike S. raises!!!

Answer (score 0):

Found few problems, which would not solve your problem...

1) With this

```
for (c = 0; c < len; c += 1) {
     last += 1;
}
```

you are getting pointer "last" set to end of string. Btw, this for cycle is useless - simpler would be `last = output + len;`

2) You do not have declared the "temp" variable. How you can compile this code? And then, the temp variable is not used..

3) **may be one of the main problems!** - you have input as array of pointers to string. You may want to have array of characters (also known as string) - so dont use `char * array[999]` but `char array[999]`

3) Why you have `if (strlen(*argv) > 100)` and array of length 999?

4) `*input = *argv;` is invalid. After you repair oyur definitions of char arrays, it should be input = *argv. And, of course, you don't need to do this, just call it with `function(*argv)`. Better would be `function[argv[1]]` or what.

5) Have some time with basics of C language, dont forget to look at working with pointers, arrays and **const** keyword.

Have a nice day